# SQL Server Express : how to allow remote connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

I am trying to allow remote connections for SQL Server Express. When I connect from machine A to connect to SQL Server on machine B using Visual Studio, I get an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

I followed the following steps below which did not help.

- Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you want to connect to from a remote computer. Turn on the SQL Server Browser service. Configure the firewall to allow network traffic that is related to SQL Server and to the SQL Server Browser service.

In fact I tried by turning off firewalls entirely but no luck. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to open the SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable TCP/IP.  This is not enabled by default.  Port 1433 will need to be open for remote connections.

- SQL Server Configuration Manager

  - SQL Server Network Configuration
  - Protocols for $InstanceName
  - Right hand pane select TCP/IP and enable

Comment: Thank you. I tried the steps you mentioned but that does not help either. When I run netstat -a , i do not see TCP port listening for 1433 . I have opened the tcp port for 1433 in firewall configuration. Also When I look at the ip addressess tab of tcp/ip properties, I notice Ip1 to IPAll area boxes. Should I change dynamic port from 0 to specify port number 1433 ? If so for which IP (n) , Is it for loopback adapter IP section ? or should I include TCP Port for IPAll ? Pls let me know.

Comment: For IPAll. Regardless why don't you test first and see?